# Cant use BigInt in TS project regardless of es2020

Tags: javascript, typescript, bigint, ecmascript-2020

I have simple TS project where this is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
  }
}
```

And I have one file, `script.ts` with following code inside

`BigInt(2);`

Unfortunatelly, when I execute `tsc script.ts`, I receive this error:
`Cannot find name 'BigInt'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2020' or later.`

Why is that happening? Isn't my library set to correct version?

Comment: Is library supposed to be an array? (I'm not sure, but try this) Edit: looks like it is supposed to be an array

Comment: Per the duplicate question, try running just `tsc` (without `script.ts`). That makes sure `tsconfig.json` is actually read (when specifying a single source file, tsconfig.json is ignored). I've tried this locally and confirmed that it fixes the problem.

Comment: Anyone coming here who is having this problem in Visual Studio, I found the solution to be to install the `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` NuGet package as per [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/download).

Answer (score 0):

BigInt is relativele new feature in Typescript, So in order to use it you have to specify **target: esnext** in your **tsconfig.json**

In your code you can create BigInt with **n** suffix, like this:

```
const bigIntNumber = 1n
```

Comment: `target: es2020` is enough (the advice to use `esnext` dates back to when ES2020 didn't exist yet), but `tsconfig.json` must actually be used. See the duplicate question.